# In yasm, define a string whose contents are equal to a macro argument value

Tags: assembly, x86, yasm

Inside a macro, I'd like to declare a string whose value is equal to the textual value of a macro argument.

For example, I want something like:

```
%macro foo 1
;; some other stuff that might use %1 unquoted
db "%1",0
%endmacro

foo bar
```

Which after macro expansion should result in the assembly:

```
db "bar",0
```

Which would assemble to the the string "bar" with a trailing null.

Comment: nasm has `%defstr` maybe yasm too?

Comment: @Jester - [unfortunately not](https://github.com/yasm/yasm/issues/95).